# Issue connecting to Websphere application server from local machine

Tags: websphere

I'm trying to connect to IBM WAS from local machine. I'm trying to connect to server using following code:

> Properties Props = new Properties()
>   Props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE,
>   AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP)
>   Props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true")
>   Props.setProperty(AdminClient.CACHE_DISABLED, "false")
>   Props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "WebAS")
>   Props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "WebAS")
>   Props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, "127.0.0.1")
>   Props.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, "9060")
>   Props.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, "user")
>   Props.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, "password")
>   System.setProperty("com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL", /*specified location of
>   file*/ "ssl.client.props") Props.setProperty("com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL",
>   /*specified location of file*/ "ssl.client.props") //I generated
>   keystore.jks `
>   Props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",directory.toURI().toURL()+"keystore‌​.jks"
>   ); Props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
>   directory.toURI().toURL()+"keystore.jks");
>   this.adminClient=AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(Props)

When run the following code, I get following error

```
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host 127.0.0.1 at port 9043.
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/security/certclient/util/PkSsCertFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.security.certclient.util.PkSsCertFactory
```

I looked up for classname: com.ibm.security.certclient.util.PkSsCertFactory to include. I cannot find neither the IBM jar file or groupId, artifact id, version. Please help me out

Comment: What JVM are you using to run the client? If I remember it right that missing class is part of IBM jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Export the dmgr's CA certificate to nodes truststore and give a try.

As I can see your node agent is taking port 9043 to connect to dmgr, if all configurations made are default, then this should not happen.

please check your nodes and dmgrs serverindex.xml file.